# How to use `foreach()` in ajax call

Tags: functions, loop, ajax, jquery

I have written a code for retrieving data from the database using the ajax for WordPress. The following code is the one written in the  `functions.php`. The code is for getting the id and names of subcategories under a category id which is defined as `$cat` . The result, i need to display as a drop down list

```
function fetchData(){
  global $wpdb;
    $catId = $_POST['key']; // value from the ajax

        // Now we want to JSON encode these values to send them to $.ajax success.
      if($catId){
         $result_fromDB = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM  sub_category where categor_id = '".$catId."'");
          echo "<option value='".$catId."' >".$catId."</option>"; //This line is returned in ajax. this is a test code
         foreach ($result_fromDB as $subcat) {
                           echo "<option value='".$subcat->id."' >".$subcat->sub_category_name."</option>"; // This line doesnt returned, getting only **<option></option>** in console
          }
      }

        die();
    }
```

The code corresponding to the ajax is,

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
    data: {
         'key' : catId,
        'action': "fetch_data" // very important
    },
    success : function (data) {
             console.log(data);
             jQuery('#sub_cat').html(data);
            }
  });
```

Can anyone give the reason and answer for not  getting the data in the `foreach()`/`loop`

Comment: Do a `var_dump( $result_fromDB );` after `$result_fromDB` is defined, and inspect the `var_dump()` output. Is it actually returning the result that you expected? Try also `echo $wpdb->last_error;` right before the `foreach()` call.

Comment: @SallyCJ thanks _buddy_, it was a mistake in the query, that retrieved using the last_error.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped you. But I suggest you to use [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) to avoid SQL injections. You can also alternatively escape the `$catId` via `esc_sql()`. See [this article](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you found the error in the comments given to you on the post, and that is good.

However, it should be pointed out that your code contains both an SQL Injection vulnerability, as well as a Reflected XSS vulnerability.

```
$catId = $_POST['key']; // value from the ajax
...
$result_fromDB = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM  sub_category where categor_id = '".$catId."'");
```

This is an SQL Injection. Basically, you are taking input provided by the user, and directly putting it into an SQL statement without any form of sanitization.

You could fix this by properly using `$wpdb->prepare()` before running the query against the database, or by simply validating that the "key" that you're getting is of the form that you expect it to be.

```
$catId = $_POST['key']; // value from the ajax
...
echo "<option value='".$catId."' >".$catId."</option>";
```

Similarly, this code echoes back input directly to the browser. This is called Reflected XSS because one could simply send it a `<script>` code, and have that script run in the context of your website. This could be used in numerous ways against you, although most of them would require some form of social engineering, like tricking you into visiting a malicious webpage in your browser.

Always validate inputs. Always sanitize outputs. Always properly prepare SQL statements. No exceptions.